# How to vertical center an image inside anchor inside div?

Tags: css, centering

Tried a lot already like, verticle-align and line-height, but without success. 
This is what I have so far from trying suggestions from the internet, but as said before without success.

```
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="example.png" width="150" height="50">
            </a>
        </div>
```

css:

```
        div.logo
        {
            height: 60px;

            margin-top: 0px;

            float:left;

            > a
            {
                height:60px;

                line-height: 60px;

                > img
                {
                    display:inline-block;

                    vertical-align: middle;
                    line-height: 60px;

                    float:left;
                }
            }
        }
```

Already thanks in advance for the replies.

Comment: First of all, if you set `float`, then the `display` property has no effect, all `floated`elements are block level elements. And second: you must to explain better what you need and what you get.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I want to center verticle center the image inside the div.

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: @Paulie_D Ah sorry, forgot to add height and width, because there is some smarty code in it, and that will only confuse the question (maybe). So I made it a basic html code.

Comment: If we don't know the relevant circumstances you're likely to get wrong answers.

Comment: I already edited it inside, now it's fully complete, except the link etc.

Comment: Check this article for a solution.  There are a few ways to achieve vertical centering. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Thanks for reply guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `display: table-cell` to the `<a>` tag you'll achieve that automatically. There are more ways but in your case this is the simplest:

```
        > a
        {
            height:60px;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle; /* this is a table cell so it works! */
            > img
            {
                display:inline-block;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Gotta do some research on table-cell I guess :). (Will accept answer in 4 mins)

Comment: You are welcome. That's a simple trick , as I said there are a lot of ways, but in this case is the simplest. table cells works with vertical-align as the `<td valign="middle">` property in old HTML methodology. If it's not a table cell, vertical align will behave different.

Comment: Great! Thanks for explaining! I can't sadly, need 15 reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.logo {
     display: table;
     height: 60px;
}

.logo a {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

or

.logo {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo a {
  display: block; 
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute; 
  top:50%; 
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```